# Distance of the centre of the object from the centre of the image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

If we apply object detection on an image containing a playing card, then it will make bounding box around that card. Now my question is this that is there any way to find the distance between the center of the card(bounding box) and the center of the whole image?

Comment: The bounding box should have some anchor point `(x, y)` and some dimensions `(w_b, h_b)` (width, height). Calculate the center point `(cx_b, cy_b)` of the bounding box from that information. The image has dimensions `(w_i, h_i)` (width, height). Calculate the center point `(cx_i, cy_i)` of the image from that information. Finally, calculate the euclidean distance between `(cx_b, cy_b)` and `(cx_i, cy_i)`,

Answer (score 0):

If the bounding box has bottom-left coordinate `(x1, y1)` and top-right `(x2, y2)`, then its center'll be `((x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2)`. Same in the case of the whole image.

Now, determine the distance by using `sqrt((c1x-c2x)^2 + (c1y-c2y)^2)`

Here, `(c1x, c1y)` is the center of the image and `(c2x, c2y)` is that of the bounding box